# Did Getafix ever drink the magic potion himself?

Tags: asterix

It seems like Getafix, the druid (called Panoramix in most languages) usually just cooks it and serves it to Asterix and the rest of the Gauls.

Are there any examples of Getafix drinking the potion himself?

Comment: Something about not getting high on his own supply. He's there for others to get their fix.

Comment: I remember that the druid was called Panoramix, not Getafix?

Comment: @4.12.22.4.18.0. only in the French translation - in English it was Getafix.  In some other translations, he was Magigamix.  Given that the English translation probably sold the best, most people will know him by Getafix.

Comment: In the Spanish translation it's Panoramix too.

Comment: In the Swedish translation, it is Miraculix.

Comment: Geez, why would they translate the name like that?!

Comment: @Moo, French isn't translation, French is the original (though not for all the later sequels).

Comment: @Mithoron, apparently most of the names are puns (though I don't understand them myself, not knowing French), so some of the translators tried to make up puns appropriate for the other languages instead.

Comment: [Wikipedia has most of the translations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Asterix_characters).

Comment: I'm pretty sure he drank it in book 1, when Asterix and Getafix were escaping from the Romans. I don't have the books with me though, so I cannot confirm.

Comment: @Moo not by a long shot. there has been about 130M books in the original French version, vs possibly 23M in the UK

Comment: @JanHudec what sequels?

Comment: @njzk2 not just the UK uses English - I read all the Asterix series in English but outgrew them by the time I moved back to the UK...

Comment: @njzk2 Of the (animated) moves “Asterix Conquers America” is German and “Asterix and the Vikings” is Danish (and because of that, their Czech translations mix up the names).

Comment: It's Miraculix in German as well and yes as Jan mentiones the names usually have some hidden meaning. Not sure about the French original, but in german it comes from miracle and in English it alsmost sounds like a drug dealer to get-a-fix.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Yes.**

In addition to the cases mentioned in other answers, Getafix drinks the potion he made before the battle in [*Asterix and the Great Divide*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterix_and_the_Great_Divide) (issue #25, published in 1980), p. 27:
[image: drink]
After that is the first (I think) occurrence in the series when Getafix fights, p. 28:
[image: fight]

The second one is in [*Asterix and Obelix all at sea*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterix_and_Obelix_All_at_Sea) (issue #30, published in 1996), in which Getafix dives into the sea after a bottle of magic potion, gets attacked by sharks, takes a sip of the potion, and scares the sharks away. Yes, this happened. Though mostly off-screen, he only says about the sharks afterward.

[image: Asterix Album 30 - Getafix dives into the ocean to]

If I remember correctly, these are all cases from comics written and drawn by Uderzo, in which Getafix drank the potion in order to gain extra strength (and use it). There were no such occurrences in comics written by Goscinny and drawn by Uderzo (again, if memory serves me right). I did not read the newest ones by Ferri and Conrad, so I have no info about that. There is in the other answer though.

Comment: Oh, Arnaud D. mentioned the Great Divide in the comment under the approved answer, didn't notice that. He was first.

Comment: That's more than fine: that was just a comment, you provided an actual answer, with the relevant panels and everything. Even if you had read the comment first, that would still have been fine. Answers posted as comments are fair game, and posting proper answers is much better for the site. So thanks, and welcome!

Comment: @SMS Added the picture to prove your claim, also fixed some spelling.

Comment: I posted the (now deleted) comment so that someone could check the actual books to confirm (couldn't do it myself), so +1. I'll just reiterate that [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterix_and_the_Great_Divide) (in the *Notes* section) agrees with you that these are the only instances of Getafix using the potions in comics drawn by Uderzo.

Comment: @BjornEriksson thanks! Concerning the 'all at sea': actually I did have the Polish translation at hand, but no scanner or English version. Also, the 'bottle' is actually the 'gourd' - there was a more fancy world in Polish version too, but I didn't know the english one. But I guess that 'bottle' makes the description more clear.

Answer (score 29):

## Yes

On page 42 of *[Asterix and the Missing Scroll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterix_and_the_Missing_Scroll)* (issue #36, published in 2015), Getafix is shown directly drinking the magic potion.

[image]

> ###### [first panel]
>
> Asterix: "Go easy, Getafix!"
> Getafix: "We have no time to lose.  A single dose won't be addictive."
>
> ###### [second panel]
>
> [Getafix drinks.  He is shown flying in air with sparks and smoke etc.]
>
> ###### [third panel]
>
> Getafix: "By Toutatis, it's certainly strong stuff!"
> Asterix: (as Obelix reaches for the gourd) "Not you Obelix!"

---

They need to return to the village quickly.  Getafix is drawn with jagged edges for the next couple of pages.

Comment: Good find! Although this isn't his _own_ magic potion, it's that of another druid, Archeopterix (and a bit concentrated, which explains the strong effect it has on both Getafix and Asterix).

Comment: It's not entirely clear.  Archaeopterix states that the potions he has are the prototypes.  I took it as meaning that Getafix brewed it himself years ago and then gave a sample to Archaeopterix to keep (sort of like a copyright library keeping a copy of each book).  Certainly it has been stored for some time which is why it is so strong.

Comment: Does anyone else find it disconcerting that this suggests that Asterix and the other villagers are _addicts_?!

Comment: @DavidW Isn't that implicit in the name "Get-a-fix"? (in the English versions)

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez That's a really good point.  I can only offer the excuse that my younger self read right past that.  (I think I interpreted it more in the sense of "fix for what ails you," since Getafix could often solve whatever health problems came up; including once making chicken soup, IIRC.)

Comment: That book isn't written or illustrated by the original people.

Comment: @hat But Uderzo was still supervising the work of the new authors and validating their ideas.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Uderzo was never the writter, only the drawer. And some purists would say that things went down the drain when Goscinny died. I mean, there's an Asterix with Aliens... In my eyes, this isn't canon.

Answer (score 18):

As Asterix returns from his failed quest for rock oil in *[Asterix and the Black Gold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterix_and_the_Black_Gold)* (issue #26, published in 1981), Getafix tells him

> "Fortunately, after conducting a few experiments, I managed to substitute beetroot juice instead. We run just as well on beetroot juice, and it tastes nicer!"

[image: Three panels from Asterix and the Black Gold. In the first, Asterix exclaims to Getafix, "Rock oil, of course! Black gold! The vital ingredient of the magic potion!", to which Getafix replies, "Oh, yes, petra oleum!" In the second panel, Getafix explains, "Don't worry! Fortunately, after conducting a few experiments, I managed to substitute beetroot juice instead. We run just as well on beetroot juice, and it tastes nicer!" In the third panel, Asterix has fainted, to Getafix' surprise.]

The fact that Getafix says that it tastes nicer, suggests that he has tried it himself, although he may have heard it from the persons he tested it on.

Comment: ...or he could have just used the villagers to taste-test. I think this question excludes sampling a tiny amount of the potion for seasoning.

Answer (score 18):

In album 7, [Asterix and the big fight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterix_and_the_Big_Fight), Getafix drinks a potion. It is not The Magic potion though but definitely a special one.

In the story, Getafix loses his memory and his mind. He brews a bunch of potions together with Psychoanalytix, another insane druid, that has random and decorative effects. Finally, they both put all the ingredients they have left in the cauldron and samples the result, which cures Getafix.

The resulting potion was the combined work of both druids, and the good result was a pure coincidence, but he was shown drinking it.

[image: Asterix album 7, Getafix drinking a potion.]

There are also instances where he has been brewing the potion and sampled it while it is still boiling. For example in Album 23 [Obelix and Co](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obelix_and_Co.) he is making the potion while talking to Asterix and Geriatrix and tastes it to see if it is ready.

[image: Asterix album 23, Getafix sampling the potion]

In neither case, he drinks it to get strong, but I think it is as close as we will get.

Comment: Should that other insane druid be Psychoanalyti**x**?

Comment: @ilkkachu  That is correct. Good find. Fixed now.